# How does google filter which marker it will display on the google map? Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently, I'm making an android app with google map. I noticed that not all markers are displayed on screen. Example, I search for  restaurants, it will only display some markers of restaurants. I tried to observe how google map displays it if it's by through ratings of establishments or other algorithm. But according to what I have observed, even those unpopular establishments display in the marker. Does anyone know how google map do this? Is it by random? or there's an algorithm?

Comment: I believe that this question is unanswerable, because only Google knows that. That is their propriate solution so I would not expect that anyone (apart Googlers) has any idea about that.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Do you have an idea though if there is a limit of number of markers for free google api? Is it true that it's 20? @jakubbialkowski